# Android MediaPlayer throws error after 30 plays

Tags: android

Ok so I'm coding a simple application for calling/dialing, and I have created button for each number. I'm trying to implement sound with MediaPlayer class so whenever user clicks/taps the button sound plays. And it is working, but after 30 clicks sound is not playing, only if I restart the app, and again I can only hear the sound for 30 clicks after that stops and I get the error.

I have tried with the SoundPool class as well, but again after 30 clicks I cannot hear the sound. Any solutions?

**onButtonClick method:**

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.button_sound);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            } else {
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.start();
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Error Log:**

> 11-29 23:01:03.632 12572-12572/com.phonecalldemo E/MediaPlayer-JNI:
>   QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present 11-29 23:01:03.662
>   12572-12572/com.phonecalldemo E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle
>   controller already set 11-29 23:01:03.672
>   12572-12572/com.phonecalldemo E/MediaPlayer: error (-19, 0) 11-29
>   23:01:03.682 12572-12572/com.phonecalldemo E/MediaPlayer: Error
>   (-19,0)

Comment: I can't tell you a specific reason why this is happening but why 30 clicks? Is it the same number every time? Is it possible that something happened, like your device rotated? Also you should you `this` as the context and not `getApplicationContext()` which might be part of the problem. (this is the Activity which is itself a Context)

Comment: Yeah 30 clicks more or less (1-3 varies). No device is not rotating, I set screen orientation to portrait on my activity. I changed getApplicationContext to 'this', and it's still the same. I'm getting that error: 

E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
11-30 11:40:57.080 12114-12114/com.phonecalldemo E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present

Comment: Look on Google for `MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set` I have found many questions and answers on that.

Comment: @NicolasMaltais
I found the solution by myself, added new reply.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I have found the solution, here is my new code, for those of you who still have trouble with this kind of error:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.button_sound);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mp.release();
                    }
                });
```